# I have a step-by-step process in jQuery, is there a better way to code it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a step-by-step process that guides a user through a setup process. I want all the code contained in one page (meaning I have setup.php, not step1.php, step2.php, and step3.php). I've coded it in jQuery like this: (it only shows one step at a time)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide all sections
    $("article").hide();

    // Show intro
    $("#intro").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
        // Listen for user to click "next" link
        $("#intro .next").click(function() {
            // Hide intro
            $("#intro").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast", function() {
                // Show EULA section
                $("#eula").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
                    // Listen for user to click "next" link
                    $("#eula .next").click(function() {
                        $("#eula").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast", function() {
                            // Show site section
                            $("#site").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
                                // Listen for user to click "next" link
                                $("#site .next").click(function() {
                                    $("#site").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast", function() {
                                        // Show database section
                                        $("#database").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
                                            // Listen for user to click "next" link
                                            $("#database .next").click(function() {
                                                $("#database").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast", function() {
                                                    // Show email section
                                                    $("#email").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
                                                        $("#email .next").click(function() {
                                                            $("#email").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast", function() {
                                                                // Submit form to PHP script
                                                                $("#done").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {

                                                                });
                                                            });
                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                });
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Yes, I realize this is terribly ugly, but I don't know another way to do it? Can anyone recommend a better way?

Comment: If you turn it on its side it's a graph of how awesome it is. Seems a little peaky.

Comment: That's some hot callback action. You might want to look into jQuery.Deferred().

Comment: Maybe you should just rearrange your submit links and use this kind of layout? See Jquery Code in [this](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/how-to-create-a-multi-step-signup-form-with-css3-and-jquery) ! Is it what you want ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use named function pointers in place of anonymous functions to break this up, it would really help the indenting.

Using your example, here are the first couple steps:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Hide all sections
    $("article").hide();

    // Show intro
    $("#intro").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", Step1);
});


// Listen for user to click "next" link
function Step1() {
    $("#intro .next").click(Step2);
}

// Hide intro
function Step2() {
    $("#intro").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast", Step3);
}

// Show EULA section
function Step3() {
    $("#eula").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", Step4);
}

function Step4() {
    // Continue this pattern until you reach the final step
}
```

Comment: Uh, please not. Never create numbered variables - there is a data structure dedicated for that.

Comment: @bergi actually I was illustrating an example here and wanted the steps to be clear. If you feel a style rule was broken and that needs a -1 then fine, but it has nothing to do with the problem the OP was asking about.

Comment: This is certainly more clean that my old way of doing it. I'll look into the alternative data structures @Bergi, but I may end up going with this since it's so simple. Plus it allows me to modify individual steps later, should I need to.

Comment: But it does not allow you to insert individual steps [easily]. Use an array of functions.

Comment: @Bergi I think it's more of a personal style decision. IMO using an array of functions does not make it any easier or harder to insert new functions. They should contain more descriptive names rather than Step1, Step2, etc.

Comment: OK, yes, descriptive names are another option. But StepN is just bad style.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save the step the user are on a variable and make your code more simple wich a case.

```
switch (step) 
{ 
   case '1': $("#intro").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast");
   case '2': $("#eula").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast");
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed yourself, the code is repeating the following pattern:

```
$("#intro").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
    // Listen for user to click "next" link
    $("#intro .next").click(function() {
        // Hide intro
        $("#intro").fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast", function() { ...
```

and just with different elements. So, you can easily build a generator for this piece:

```
function getStep(id, callback) {
    return function() {
        var el = $("#"+id);
        el.fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
            // Listen for user to click "next" link
            el.find(".next").click(function() {
               // Hide it
               el.fadeOut("fast").delay(500).slideUp("fast", callback);
            });
        });
    };
}

getStep("intro", getStep("eula", getStep("site", getStep("database", getStep("email", function() {
    // Submit form to PHP script
    $("#done").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
        ...
    });
 })))));
```

Of course you might use a loop (or even a recursice function) to build the steps. If you'd change the two parameters of `getStep`, you could use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
 ["intro", "eula", "site", "database", "email"].reduce(function(cb, id){
     return getStep(id, cb);
   }, function() {
     // Submit form to PHP script
     $("#done").fadeIn("slow").delay(500).slideDown("slow", function() {
        ...
     });
   });
```

---

Obviously, it would also be easier to just add the click listeners to the already existing (but hidden) elements right away in the DOMready, instead of doing it recursively only in the fadeIn-callback.